Python code to install PostgreSQL is not outputting anything
I am currently writing a python script which will automate the install of PostgreSQL and create a PostgreSQL Database and Schema. The python script should run a number of Bash commands to install PostgreSQL on the server but at the moment when I run it, it is not outputting anything back in the shell.
The script looks something like this
import sys
import subprocess
import os

db_server = sys.argv[1]
db_version = sys.argv[2]
app_name = sys.argv[3]

sys.stdout.write('start01')

cmd = 'whoami'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
sys.stdout.write('out : {0}'.format(out))
sys.stdout.write('error : {0}'.format(err))

cmd = 'cd /tmp'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)

cmd = 'pwd'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
sys.stdout.write('out : {0}'.format(out))
sys.stdout.write('error : {0}'.format(err))

....

When I run it like this:
python3 CreatePG_DB.py 'testserver' '13' 'testapp'
the script runs but doesn't output anything.
I am new to running shell scripts via Python so any advice would be much appreciated :)
I tried running this script and it appears to run but doesn't output anything. I am not very familiar with using the subproccess library and I am also new to running linux shell scripts with python.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

why don't you use print()? If you use sys.stdout.write then you have to add '\n' on your own. And it may use buffer which sends on screen only when there is \n in text. Or you may have to use sys.stdout.flush()

BTW: subprocess may gives response as bytes and you may need out.decode('utf-8') to get it correctly. Other problem - every subprocess runs own shell and using cd is useless because next subprocess will use old folder. You will need os.chdir(). Frankly, I would use subprcess.run() instead of .popen()

@furas print() and os.chdir work for me, thanks!
